# Programmatically render GeoJSON to image file

Tags: python, geojson

I have a series of GeoJSON objects that I wish to render on a map programatically.

I can use http://geojson.io and upload my GeoJSON but how do I programatically do this and export a PNG or other image file?

https://github.com/mapbox/geojson.io looked great, but it posts publicly to the geojson.io site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to get hold of the MapBox SDK for Python: `pip install mapbox`

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-py

Then you can use a service like: Static Maps V4 (alternatively Static Styles V1 also looks interesting)

https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/pages/static_classic.html

This is the code from their example: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-py/blob/master/docs/static.md#static-maps

*main.py*

```
from mapbox import Static

service = Static()

portland = {
    'type': 'Feature',
    'properties': {'name': 'Portland, OR'},
    'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [-122.7282, 45.5801]}}
response = service.image('mapbox.satellite', features=[portland])

# add to a file
with open('./output_file.png', 'wb') as output:
    _ = output.write(response.content)
```

run: `export MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN="YOUR_MAP_BOX_TOKEN" && python main.py`

The above code is working for me and creates a png of the surrounding area of the provided data, as shown below. The `features` attribute should accept your geojson objects.

[image: Output of python script: main.py]

If you want to use a custom MapBox style then you need to use Static Styles V1

https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/?language=Python#static

*main.py*

```
from mapbox import StaticStyle

service = StaticStyle()

portland = {
    'type': 'Feature',
    'properties': {'name': 'Portland, OR'},
    'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [-122.7282, 45.5801]}}
response = service.image('YOUR_USERNAME', 'YOUR_STYLE_ID', features=[portland])


# add to a file
with open('./output_file.png', 'wb') as output:
    _ = output.write(response.content)
```

[image: Styled map output]

I've also created a repository on GitHub with an example function:
https://github.com/sarcoma/MapBox-Static-Style-Python-Script

Comment: Changing the [map id](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/244797/70242) from `'mapbox.satellite'` to `'mapbox.streets'` improves the image quality a lot.

Comment: This only works for small data. With bigger amounts, you get: `mapbox.errors.InputSizeError: GeoJSON is too large for the static maps API, must be less than 4096 characters`

Comment: You'll need to open a new question for that.

Comment: @MartinThoma have you found any solutions for large geojsons?

Answer (score 0):

The [geojson-renderer](https://github.com/softwaretechnik-berlin/geojson-renderer) is a command line tool that renders geojson content on top of map tiles. It can produce SVG or PNG as output. The source of the map tiles is configurable. To use it from Python you could shell out.